# '+' or parseInt() - which one is efficient to convert string to integer in javascript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript codes, I have seen people using '+' character to convert string to integer as in -

```
var i = +"2";
```

another way is just using parseInt() method as following -

```
var i = parseInt("2");
```

I want to know which one is efficient?

Sorry I should also add that, I am dealing with integers only and the data is huge so even a little difference in performance would be good for me.

Comment: Use [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com) website, if you really care.

Comment: Stylistically, `parseInt` is more "efficient" as it will most likely save you more time on debugging

Comment: First it would depend on which browser your are using.  Also, why don't use just write a timing test.

Comment: There's no conclusive answer, so go with what reads best. Also `+"1.2"` doesn't return an integer.

Comment: Just did a quick timing test and found out - in firefox(latest) '+' is run almost two times faster than parseInt, but in chrome(latest) and IE9 '+' is slightly slower than parseInt.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, don't worry about it, use whatever is more convinient for you and the actual case; micro-optimizations like this are useless. Id' say just remember that you might need to pass in the radix parameter into `parseInt` if your number is (or looks) octal or some other format.

Comment: Actually, only one option truly converts to an integer :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the Browser.

i've created a nasty little [Testcase](http://jsperf.com/stringtonumber) for some String-To-Number conversion possibilities i know.

Ive also added possibilities to convert to floating-point-numbers, as in Javascript Numbers are Numbers, no matter if they have floating point or not.

Check it out. Corrections and suggestions appreciated!

As some other folks around here said in the comments below the question: I also think its better not to think to much about it, bu to focus on readability..